# Bash Script - How take a result of command and use it

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to know how to do this, if for example, when executing a command in a script, retrieve the message linked to this command.
For example "AZERTY already exists, please check the error" is the message that comes out after a command (wrong), how do I so that if my BASH script sees this info, tell it to stop the script?

Comment: Variable="$(echo $message)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly should not check the error message.  Instead just do:

```
cmd || exit
```

If `cmd` fails and writes the message "AZERTY already exists, please check the error" to stderr, then that message will appear and the script will exit with whatever non-zero value `cmd` exited with.  Some commands return non-zero values that have meaning, and you may want to suppress that (for consistent return values from your script) or change that with something like:

```
cmd || exit 1
```

On the other hand, if `cmd` is poorly written and returns a zero value when it "fails" (I'm putting that in quotes since a reasonable definition of "fail" is "return non-zero"), then that is a bug in `cmd` which should be fixed.

Comment: The command I use is not really fails, she's only result a text : Fileset DBbackup_orintb4h already exists.
mmcrfileset: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.
and just continue to the next command

Comment: I'm sorry, but if a command writes an error message which includes the string "Command failed" but does not fail, then you need to redesign the way that command works.  Note that `echo Command failed` is *not* writing an error message.  But `echo Command failed >&2` should be re-written as `echo Command failed >&2 && false`.  Conventions like this are extremely important and ought to be honored.

Comment: Ok my bad William, it's my fault. I wrote the script (without doing it on purpose) to keep this going. With one modification plus your solution, it works. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using strict mode in all your bash scripts. http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/

Basically put this at the top

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'
```

The option you specifically asked about is `-e`

> The set -e option instructs bash to immediately exit if any command [1] has a non-zero exit status. You wouldn't want to set this for your command-line shell, but in a script it's massively helpful. In all widely used general-purpose programming languages, an unhandled runtime error - whether that's a thrown exception in Java, or a segmentation fault in C, or a syntax error in Python - immediately halts execution of the program; subsequent lines are not executed.

Comment: Note that it is generally considered best practice to avoid `set -e` since it has many pitfalls and its behavior is different across different shells or different versions of the same shell.  It is better to explicitly exit than to rely on `set -e`

Comment: The Wooledge wiki has good articles about [`set -e`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and [`set -u`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112). I personally don't like changing the default for `IFS`; instead, I use something like ShellCheck to point out all unquoted expansions. All in all, "strict mode" is way too opinionated for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ./command | grep -q 'AZERTY already exists, please check the error'; then
  echo "Error found, exiting"
  exit 1
fi
```